# ffmpegintrop namespace not recognized

Tags: build, ffmpeg, win-universal-app

I used the sample ffmpegintrop project provided by Microsoft, I followed all steps of building and compilation and it was succesfully built. But then I tried to run the project it fails to build giving error : 'type or namespace ffmpegintrop cannot be resolved'. As you can see in the attached image below that using statement of the namespace is also giving error that it is not working. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Did you try [Compile and Use FFmpeg Libraries for Windows Runtime (Windows 10 or Windows 8.1 Apps)](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/WinRT)?

Comment: yes sir i have tried that and i followed every step, so it compiled succesfully the libraries in the output folder of ffmpeg, but project in visual studio is still not building.